# Deploy on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I created my portfolio with react+sass, I added some states and jquery animations
I deployed my portfolio on Github-pages. The portfolio was made just with ReactJS.
When I open the link it appears white, just with title and favicon.
There is no error on console
somebody can help me?

## My App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import './components/styles/main.scss'
import Home from './components/home'
import Works from './components/works'
import About from './components/about'


function App() {
  return (
    <Router basename={window.location.pathname || ''}>
    <div className="App">
       <Route exact path="/home"  component={Home} />
       <Route exact path="/works" component={Works} />
       <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## My Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Portofolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://batistatony.github.io/batistaoliveira/home",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

link:
https://batistatony.github.io/batistaoliveira/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `homepage` in package.json with `"."`, like this:

```
  "homepage": ".",
```

This will resolve the white page problem, your portfolio should be accessible at: https://batistatony.github.io/batistaoliveira/

Now, react-router-dom's `BrowserRouter` will not work well with GitHub Pages, you currently use `HashRouter` which is great, just remove the basename parameter. GitHub Pages doesn't support any URL rewrite feature, so you will not be able to use `BrowserRouter` with a link like: https://batistatony.github.io/batistaoliveira/home, you will need to use https://batistatony.github.io/batistaoliveira/#/home (with `HashRouter`).

Comment: I apologize, assumed you have BrowserRouter. Just remove the basename from parameters.